# Stacked text in a stacked area chart using Altair

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite, vega

I wanted to know if it is possible to have text marks in the corresponding areas of a stacked area chart.

I used `median` aggregate to get single X and Y axis values otherwise it shows text all through the edge of the chart. However, this aggregate is not foolproof, as if the chart is a little convoluted, then the X axis position may not be the best possible region for the text to be displayed into.

This is as far as I have got -

```py
X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
V=[1,1,1,2,4,8,6,4,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,1,1,1,1,4,8,4,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,5,4]
key=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
K = [y for x in key for y in (x)*9]

demo = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'V': V, 'K': K})
a = alt.Chart(demo).mark_area().encode(
    x='X:O',
    y='V:Q',
    color='K:N'
)
t = alt.Chart(demo).mark_text().encode(
    x='median(X):O',
    y='median(V):Q',
    text=alt.Text('K:N',)
)
a+t
```

[image]

**Issue**

- The text is not in its proper region.
- The order of the text is also wrong.

It's not that I don't understand why I have these issues, I do actually(the Y position is not aggregating as "stacked" on top of each other), but I do not know how to solve it or if it is even doable as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just build a separate dataframe for the text and use that as source. It is much easier and customizable than doing all sorts of transformations in Altair if such a thing is even possible in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
V=[1,1,1,2,4,8,6,4,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,1,1,1,1,4,8,4,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,5,4]
key=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
K = [y for x in key for y in (x)*9]

demo = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'V': V, 'K': K})

# find X position where the sum of V's of K's is the maximum (this is at X=6)
idxmax = demo.groupby(["X"]).sum().idxmax()[0]
# find the cumulative sum of V's at position idxmax and
# take away some offset (4) so the labels go down a bit
# iloc[::-1] reverses the order because we want cumulative to start from the bottom (from 'd')
ypos = demo.groupby(["X", "K"]).sum().loc[idxmax].iloc[::-1].cumsum()["V"] - 4
# crate a new dataframe for the text, X column=idmax, Y column=cumulative ypos, K=key
demotext = pd.DataFrame([[idxmax, y, k] for y,k in zip(ypos.tolist(), key[::-1])],
                        columns=["X", "Y", "K"])


a = (alt.Chart(demo).mark_area()
        .encode(
                x='X:O',
                y='V:Q',
                color='K:N')
    )
t = (alt.Chart(demotext).mark_text()
        .encode(
                x='X:O',
                y='Y:Q',
                text='K:N'
))

a+t
```

Output

[image: Altair Area Chart With Text]

Comment: See if you can improve it by not taking away a fixed value from Y (in this case 4) but center the each text in the middle of its corresponding area. For example 'a' and 'c' are not centered too well.

Comment: I have thought about it long and hard too and I think you may be right. There is no way from Altair or Vega-Lite to do it internally, and possibly there won't be one. It needs to be done manually with a different dataset for text.

Comment: And things get fairly complicated when the chart has peaks that are not aligned well. I think I will write my own answer for it too but accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to realize that it may not be possible to do it programmatically or maybe its not worth it because of the complexities involved like peaks that are not aligned.
Modifying the data given above slightly highlights this issue well -

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
V=[1,1,1,2,4,8,6,4,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,1,1,1,1,4,8,4,2,1,1,5,9,5,3,1,1,1,1]
key=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
K = [y for x in key for y in (x)*9]

demo = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'V': V, 'K': K})

# get the x and y positions for max values of the graph
demo.groupby('K').max()

# crate a new dataframe for the text, X column=idmax, Y column=cumulative ypos, K=key
demotext = pd.DataFrame([[idxmax, y, k] for y,k in zip(ypos.tolist(), key[::-1])],
                        columns=["X", "Y", "K"])


a = (alt.Chart(demo).mark_area()
        .encode(
                x='X:O',
                y='V:Q',
                color='K:N')
    )
t = (alt.Chart(demotext).mark_text()
        .encode(
                x='X:O',
                y='Y:Q',
                text='K:N'
))
a+t
```

[image]

I think the best and easiest way it to manually construct the data for text if you have a very convoluted graph -

```py
a = (alt.Chart(demo).mark_area()
        .encode(
                x='X:O',
                y='V:Q',
                color='K:N')
    )
t = (alt.Chart(p).mark_text()
        .encode(
                x='X:O',
                y='csum:Q',
                text='K:N'
))
a+t
```

Where `p` is -

```
    K   V   X   csum
0   a   8   6   18
1   b   7   7   7
2   c   8   6   4
3   d   9   3   4
```

[image]